# Interact between multiple volumes using VTK

Tags: 3d, rendering, render, vtk, volume

I want to render two volumes together in a single render window and allow interaction between them using VTK.

I have come upon a class called vtkmultivolume that allows multi-volume rendering
link1:https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMultiVolume.html#details
link2:https://discourse.vtk.org/t/multi-vtkvolume-rendering-problem/5060

Does this follow the same concept of vtkimagestack involving superposition of 2d objects.

Right now I have rendered the two volumes using a single renderer but I am only able to move them together. I want to be able to control each object individually.

```
*** 
//volume 1
vtkNew<vtkStructuredPointsReader> reader;
reader->SetFileName("insert path.vtk");
reader->Update();


vtkNew<vtkGPUVolumeRayCastMapper> volumeMapper;
volumeMapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());


---

*** 
//volume 2
vtkNew<vtkSTLReader>stlReader;
stlReader->SetFileName("insert path");
stlReader->Update();
vtkNew<vtkPolyDataMapper> stlMapper;
stlMapper->SetInputConnection(stlReader->GetOutputPort());
vtkNew<vtkActor> stlactor;
stlactor->SetMapper(stlMapper);


//The volume holds the mapper and the property and 
can be used to position/orient the volume
 vtkNew<vtkVolume> volume;
 volume->SetMapper(volumeMapper);
 volume->SetProperty(volumeProperty);
 ren1->AddVolume(volume);
 ren1->AddActor(stlactor);

 renWin->Render();
 iren->Start();
```